# Correctly updating an in memory cache in a dropwizard/jdbi web service

Tags: java, mysql, concurrency, transactions, dropwizard

I have a distributed web service (dropwizard/jdbi). I am keeping an in-memory cache, say a map of roll numbers and corresponding students.

These objects are built from data from multiple DAOs. So when any update on a student should happen I should perform a transaction [using @Transactional with @CreateSqlUpdate in jdbi](http://manikandan-k.github.io/2015/05/10/Transactions_in_jdbi.html)) to update the corresponding mysql tables. Also, I should invalidate the cache or map at the time of update.

My question is should this cache update/invalidation be part of a transaction i.e; if the database updates happen then only the cache invalidation happens and if the database updates happen but cache update fails somehow, the database is rolled back. What are the concurrency/consistency issues I should keep in mind here?

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to add versioning to your entities (e.g., `int Student#getVersion()`), which is persisted to `students` table.

It works this way: in each writing tx, service should check if new version, presumably received from client, is "cached version plus one", and abort write tx, if it's not the case (providing informative exception to client).

If all ok, you need to update cache to version + 1 after successful tx commit.

Your SQL `update` statements must include `... AND student.version = X`, where `X` is current cached version, so you can detect when database contains a version newer than your service cache (presumably, due to previous cache failure) and act accordingly (i.e., refresh cache to current version from DB and reject this pending write).

This way, if cached version becomes stale due to cache update failure, you'll detect it inside write tx. And no need to rollback tx if cache update fails -- after all, it's not clients' fault.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! But I am not sure whether I would have the freedom to adopt versions in cache now. One more thing is from a concurrency point, should I make sure in some way that cache invalidation happens only after the transaction is complete.

Comment: For solution above, you can update cache after tx committed. In absence of errors, it will minimize tx time. You'll detect any cache update failure in next write tx, due to versions mismatch between client data and database data.